# Why does overflow:hidden break multiple column rendering in Firefox but not in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, css-multicolumn-layout

I recently stumbled across a strange behavior in Firefox with lists in an `columns:2` div.

If the list has `overflow:hidden` set Firefox doesn't render in 2 columns anymore. rendering in Chrome it is as expected in 2 Columns (with and without overflow).

Here's a minimal example:

```js
$('button').on('click', (e) => {
  $('ul').toggleClass('overflow')
})
```

```css
div {
  columns:2;
}

ul.overflow {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>toggle overflow</button>
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
        <li>Consequuntur, ab nostrum.</li>
        <li>Quibusdam, iure, fuga.</li>
        <li>Suscipit quisquam, vel.</li>
        <li>Assumenda architecto, adipisci!</li>
        <li>Molestias, nostrum ratione.</li>
        <li>Quaerat, eveniet, in.</li>
        <li>Illum, debitis, dicta.</li>
        <li>Tempore, placeat, ea.</li>
        <li>Amet dignissimos, maiores.</li>
        <li>Odio, eos, ullam.</li>
        <li>Modi libero, quis!</li>
        <li>Aliquid, commodi, voluptates.</li>
        <li>Aperiam, magni, vel.</li>
        <li>Vitae, minima dolorum!</li>
        <li>Quidem, corporis, dolorum.</li>
        <li>Autem, minima, sit.</li>
        <li>Adipisci, odio, numquam.</li>
        <li>At, dicta, hic!</li>
        <li>Odit, blanditiis voluptate.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

On CodePen:
https://codepen.io/BugHunter2k/pen/rNaVpGG

What rendering is right? 
Is there something I can add so Firefox renders 2 columns even with `overflow:hidden`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Thierry's answer includes a solution to fix one problem, it also fixes the actual problem you're facing (inadvertently, I believe), and problematically lays blame with the wrong browser. Let's break things down:

**First, this is actually working correctly in Firefox, and incorrectly in Chrome.**

You have a div which is acting as a [multi-column container](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-multicol-1/#multi-column-container) due to `columns: 2`, which is shorthand for:

```css
div {
    column-count: 2;
    column-width: auto;
}
```

This multi-column container establishes a new [block formatting context](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#block-formatting), so any properties on descendant elements will be applied relative to the div rather than the page in this example.

One thing to keep in mind is that multi-column layouts are a bit flexible (I don't mean in relation to flexbox layout, either) ...they'll try to adhere to the values you give, but if they can fit in fewer columns, or if they have to take up more columns to fit your markup, they are likely to do that. You'll see an example of this later on in my answer.

Within the div you have an unordered list, which normally displays its children in a vertical list, but because of `columns: 2` from earlier, your `<ul>` is split automatically to fit into two columns as best it can. Because there's no `height` or `width` properties declared anywhere (in general or as `column-` properties), it just splits the contents 50-50. The misalignment you see between the two halves of the list is because `<ul>` by default has `margin-top` property which is pushing the first half of list-items down 16px (usually the size of margins on `<ul>`s).

The reason that applying `columns: 2` in `ul {}` instead of `div {}` solves your problem is because you're now splitting the `<ul>` *itself* into two columns rather than trying to squeeze a normal `<ul>` into a multi-column container however it can fit; the browser knows to apply the same formatting to the beginning of each column this way.

Now, a `<div>` is, by default, as wide as its container (because of its default `display:block;` property) and as tall as its content. If you were to add more items to the `<ul>`, the two sets of list-items would grow in height (if you have a background-color set for the div, you can see that more easily).

Referring back to that flexibility I mentioned, if you were to cap the height of your div at, say, 150px, you'd see that the number of columns increases and overflows the div by default:

```css
div {
    columns:2;
    column-rule: thin solid red; /* this value added just to illustrate the split between columns */
    height: 150px;
    background: grey; /* this value added for ease of visual comprehension */
}

ul.overflow {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>Lorem ipsum dolor.</li>
        <li>Consequuntur, ab nostrum.</li>
        <li>Quibusdam, iure, fuga.</li>
        <li>Suscipit quisquam, vel.</li>
        <li>Assumenda architecto, adipisci!</li>
        <li>Molestias, nostrum ratione.</li>
        <li>Quaerat, eveniet, in.</li>
        <li>Illum, debitis, dicta.</li>
        <li>Tempore, placeat, ea.</li>
        <li>Amet dignissimos, maiores.</li>
        <li>Odio, eos, ullam.</li>
        <li>Modi libero, quis!</li>
        <li>Aliquid, commodi, voluptates.</li>
        <li>Aperiam, magni, vel.</li>
        <li>Vitae, minima dolorum!</li>
        <li>Quidem, corporis, dolorum.</li>
        <li>Autem, minima, sit.</li>
        <li>Adipisci, odio, numquam.</li>
        <li>At, dicta, hic!</li>
        <li>Odit, blanditiis voluptate.</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

As you can see, the div is as wide as the container (no matter how big your container is) and the columns are split into three, because that's required to fit the amount of list-items you have. It does this by *overflowing* the children element as necessary to try and keep the columns an equal height. **The secret to the behavior you see when toggling the button is what `overflow: hidden;` does.**

When you apply `overflow: hidden;` to an element, it *also* establishes a new block formatting context. Creating a new block formatting context basically says "reset my layout computation from scratch here; don't factor in what the containing block was doing". In your case, it's saying "ignore the CSS column layout in the previous block formatting context and just display like a `<ul>` normally would". **Chrome isn't doing this**, but it should be. It could be a case of the implementation being wrong/incomplete, or it could be a case of Chrome devs making a decision based on what they think most people would want. Both situations are common with that vendor.

Second, Thierry's suggestion to fix the uneven vertical alignment of the two parts of the `<ul>` was to apply the `column` properties to the `<ul>`. That *particular* goal could also be accomplished by removing the `margin-top` property/setting it to `0`, but this method of solving that goal also does the following:

- Applies proper multi-column layout settings to the `<ul>` (as I mentioned before, now the browser knows to handle the list and the list-items within the context of a multi-col layout rather than just trying to squeeze in a list to a multi-column container).
- Setting the `columns` property on the `<ul>` itself means that, when a new block formatting context is created due to `overflow: hidden;`, nothing changes with regard to the `<ul>` ignoring stuff from the parent `<div>` and its block formatting context. In other words, the multi-column layout is applied within the *new* block formatting context created by `overflow: hidden;`.

This new behavior is ultimately what you want, if you are only trying to split up an unordered list into multiple columns. If you want multiple types of elements (or just multiple elements) considered for the multi-column layout, keeping it on the parent `<div>` would be necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That helped a lot to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the solution, it helped me too to better understand css . I guess I got the good answer but without the good comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a bug from Firefox.

But what you can do is put the `columns: 2;` on the `ul` and not on the `div`. It will also resolve the (unwanted?) behavior of the second column that is not align with the first column.

Don't forget to use the browsers prefix in your code. It can always help you to prevent some bugs.

Comment: What browser prefixes are you referring to? Contrary to what you suggest, they should *not* be added to code unless you *know* they're needed.

Comment: In this case, it would be the prefix `-moz-`, but the `-webkit-` too. What I understand in the MDN Doc in the Browser compatibility section, it's needed even tho I think for all modern browser it will work without it. People often told me that I need to put the prefix just to be more sure about browsers compatibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns#Browser_compatibility

Comment: If the browsers support a property itself, like `columns`, then there's no need for the prefixes unless you are concerned about specifically older versions of browsers. In practice, this is unnecessary today as all of the browsers that you would typically write prefixes for in that case are "evergreen", meaning they update automatically, and someone has to explicitly change their browser settings to stay on a specific version... meaning they're knowingly opting out of certain web features or compatibility options.

Comment: You may be right, but at my work we need to use prefixes (we use AutoPrefixer when compiling our scss) to assure that our websites are compatible with the most browsers possible. When there is prefixes, the prefixes are before so they can be use as a fallback if needed in rare cases. Is there some negatives points to use them in any way?

Comment: @ThierryLemaitre The drawbacks are 1: more verbose code and larger file sizes, and more importantly the risk that they're declared incorrectly (e.g. putting the prefixed values after the unprefixed values rather than vice versa).